# How can I optimize this python code for sorting large input?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, bubble-sort

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?) problem on HackerRank which requires you to sort a list of integers and find how many times a number was moved in order to place in the correct ascending order (bribes within the context of the problem).

My code passes 8 of the 12 test cases but fails when the input is too large with a timeout error. This seems to be a common indicator on HackerRank that the code is too slow for the problem at hand. So is there a way to optimize this code so that it runs faster on larger data sets?

```
def minimum_bribes(queue):
"""Returns the minimum number of bribes people in a queue accepted."""

# Variable to keep track of bribes
bribes = 0

# Check if queue is too chaotic
for i in queue:
    index = queue.index(i)
    if i - index > 3:
        return "Too chaotic"

# Use a bubble sort to find number of bribes
for i in range(len(queue) - 1):
    for j in range(len(queue) - 1 - i):
        if queue[j] > queue[j + 1]:
            queue[j], queue[j + 1] = queue[j + 1], queue[j]
            bribes += 1

return bribes


# Number of test cases
t = int(input())
results = []

for _ in range(t):

    # Number of people
    n = int(input())
    # Final State of queue
    q = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    # Add bribe counts to results array
    results.append(minimum_bribes(q))

# Print results
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: the link to the problem does not seem to work...

Comment: Hmm are you sure? It worked for me on different browsers just fine.

Comment: Among other issues, you might want to fix that initial loop checking for being too chaotic; you wrote it as a `O(n**2)` algorithm (because `queue.index` is `O(n)` and you call it `n` times). You can trivially simplify to `for index, i in enumerate(queue):` (removing `index = queue.index(i)` entirely), because `enumerate` is perfectly happy to provide you both value and index at once, reducing `O(n**2)` work to `O(n)` work.

Comment: Of course, the test that loop performs also seems wrong at a glance; one person can bribe at most two others, but that doesn't limit shifts in the line that much; the second person in the line can bribe the first to switch, then the third can bribe them, and so on, such that everyone in the line moves forward one place, except the first person, who moves from the front to the back. Point is, any test for excessive chaos can't naively check based on the position of any one person.

Comment: @pbegle, it works again now... don't know why it didn't yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using while loop to test the condition, if there was no swap in the previous iteration, there is no need to run a new swap iteration.

```
def minimumBribes(queue): 

     for i in queue:
            index = queue.index(i)
            if (i - index) > 3:
            print("Too chaotic")
            return    

    n = len(queue)
    swap =0
    swapped = True
    j =0    
    while swapped:
        j+=1
        swapped = False
        for i in range(n-j):
            if queue[i] > queue[i+1]:
                queue[i], queue[i+1] = queue[i+1], queue[i]
                swap +=1
                swapped = True

    print(swap)
    return swap
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I used this code along with a slight modification as suggested by @ShadowRanger to use enumerate instead and my code passed all tests.